# Apply command to every line in bash terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

I've accidentally discovered the lolcat package today.

[image]

The first thing that I though about is: it would be fantastic if i could pipe everything that comes from stdout to the terminal through lolcat to get those rainbow effects. Just imagine the pranking possibilities.

Essentially what I'm asking for is a way to apply a command to every line that comes out of a bash prompt to stdout.

Comment: -1:  While the sum total of what you say leads a person to kind of guess what you're asking, you never actually present the question.  Then, in spite of what appears to be an effort at research, the question appears (to me) to be (categorically) not useful.  If you did such a thing to a shell I used via administrative action, I'd file a complaint with your boss.  If you were a coworker, I'd want to punch you in the balls or get you fired instead of complement you for creativity.  I'd never consider doing such a thing to any user under my purview.

Answer (score 1):

Just run bash like this: **bash | lolcat**

Comment: This works, but how can I make every bash prompt that is spawned work like this? Will adding `alias bash=bash | lolcat` to bashrc work? Or to rc.local?

Answer (score 1):

In a bash session, you want to do

```
exec > >(lolcat)
```

I don't have this installed but a similar idea:

```
$ date
Sun Mar 22 20:01:23 EDT 2015
$ exec > >(rev)
$ date
5102 TDE 23:10:02 22 raM nuS
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell extension for the world's fastest website generator that I make called [Nift](https://nift.dev). It has an easter egg where you can turn on lolcat output for most things with `lolcat.on` (after starting the shell with eg. `nift sh`). You will even get rainbow output when pressing tab to get possible completion options, I doubt you get that with any other suggested solutions.

The shell extension is for [f++](https://nift.dev/docs/f++.html) which is the in-built scripting language, which has [these](https://nift.dev/docs/fns.html) functions and [these](https://nift.dev/docs/types.html) types available. But anything it doesn't recognise is run as a system call using the (probably primary/default) shell on your machine (hence calling it a shell extension in REPL shell mode).

Nift will look for a version of lolcat installed on your machine and otherwise use an in-built version of it which should be the world's fastest (it's near identical to my c++ implementation [lolcat-cc](https://github.com/n-ham/lolcat-cc) which is the world's fastest). I highly recommend installing lolcat-cc (or another version of lolcat) on top of Nift though as otherwise you are frequently running the ~5mb Nift binary for basically all system calls, instead of a <1mb binary for lolcat.

f++ is somewhat of an interesting scripting language as well. Take [this](https://pastebin.com/5FM7Hzef) script for example which creates and deletes 100k empty text files. On my machine this runs in ~3.5 seconds whereas [this](https://pastebin.com/RTXXEHBg) Bash script doing essentially the same thing takes more like 3 minutes!! Some of the cool things you might already notice from that f++ script is you can expand variables inside strings, you can define variables with types, you can expand variables in to multiple parameters with function calls, you can have LOTS more than 10k input parameters for function calls (should be able to have millions!).

You can find some more information about the Nift REPLs (including shortcuts for different platforms) [here](https://nift.dev/docs/interactive.html).

If you need to define shell variables (not through f++ but the underlying shell) then you will need to do blocks of code using the sys/system function. You can also do blocks of code for Lua(JIT) and ExprTk similarly as they are both embedded in to Nift. You can use both Lua and ExprTk with accessing/modifying f++ variables as well..

So to get this shell (extension). Install Nift through a package manager or clone, make and install off GitHub. Enter `nift sh` in to your terminal to start the Nift f++ shell extension, then enter `lolcat.on` to turn on rainbow output.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.